# Javascript Import for filesaver.js

Tags: javascript, filesaver.js

I am new to using the import function in Javascript and am mystified by the instruction on [how to install filesaver.js.](https://github.com/eligrey/FileSaver.js)

In my code I have:

```
<script src="/scripts/FileSaver.js"></script>

<script>
    import { saveAs } from 'file-saver/FileSaver';
    $("#xmlToFile").click(function() {
            var xml = $("#jobXml").val();
            var blob = new Blob([xml], { type: 'text/xml' });
            var filename = $("#Job_JobID").val();
            saveAs(blob, filename + ".txt");
        });
</script>
```

but Chrome chokes on the import line with **Unexpected Token {**

What am I doing wrong ?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The module appears to be designed for projects which use [WebPack](https://webpack.js.org/) and [Babel](https://babeljs.io/), but you are trying to load it directly into the browser without transpiling it.

Their wiki [has an example](https://github.com/eligrey/FileSaver.js/wiki/FileSaver.js-Example) showing how to use a version that is pre-transpiled for browsers:

```
<script src="http://cdn.jsdelivr.net/g/filesaver.js"></script>
<script>
      function SaveAsFile(t,f,m) {
            try {
                var b = new Blob([t],{type:m});
                saveAs(b, f);
            } catch (e) {
                window.open("data:"+m+"," + encodeURIComponent(t), '_blank','');
            }
        }

SaveAsFile("text","filename.txt","text/plain;charset=utf-8");

</script>
```

Comment: Ahh thanks -  makes so much more sense when you know whats going on. I hadn't spotted the wiki  either!

Answer (score 3):

You don't need to import saveAs 
try this

```js
    $("#xmlToFile").click(function() {
            var xml = "texte here"
            var blob = new Blob([xml], { type: 'text/xml' });
            saveAs(blob, "title" + ".txt");
        });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://fastcdn.org/FileSaver.js/1.1.20151003/FileSaver.min.js"></script>

<button id="xmlToFile">Click</button>
```

Comment: glad i could help :)

Answer (score 1):

I'm not powerful enough to comment, but wanted to add for others who may be looking, the

```
 <script src="https://fastcdn.org/FileSaver.js/1.1.20151003/FileSaver.min.js"></script>
```

usage doesn't work anymore. That site doesn't exist. You can npm install file-saver, then point to the node_modules FileSaver.js file in the `<script>` tag.

Answer (score 0):

You need to enable the Experimental Javascript Features to use import statements.

Check out this [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/import) link for further help.